# localizar php.ini no Cpanel

Tags: codeigniter

Preciso de editar o `php.ini` no CPanel, mas não encontro o painel de configuração de serviços. Estou tentando enviar e-mail com *codeigniter* no *localhost* funcionou usando *Xampp*, mas online no CPanel da este erro:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to
>     ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection timed out)
>   Filename: libraries/Email.php
>   Line Number: 1950
>   Backtrace:
>   File: /home/sermulhe/public_html/application/controllers/FrontEnd_Ctrl.php
>   Line: 261
>   Function: send
>   File: /home/sermulhe/public_html/index.php
>   Line: 292
>   Function: require_once

Comment: Só pra eu entender melhor o problema, qual seria a relação do php.ini  com o erro mencionado, neste caso? Se fosse _timeout_ do script eu até entenderia. Sua idéia é mexer no tempo de conexão do `fsockopen` via php.ini?

Answer (score 2):

Isso depende da sua hospedagem.

Algumas hospedagens permitem que você adicione um `PHP.INI` na raiz do diretório do seu site, apenas com as diretivas que você deseja alterar.

Outra dica é, como você usa o codeigniter, você pode tentar alterar o protocolo no envio do e-mail, no arquivo `email.php` dentro do diretório `application/config`, altere o protocolo para `mail` e tente enviar novamente.